# What's the background music playing on Naruto Shippuden episode 329 when Naruto meets all other jinchuuriki?

Tags: naruto, music

On *Naruto Shippuden* episode 329, there's a background music that was played when Naruto meets all jinchuuriki and they share their power with him.

The relevant scene on the [YouTube starts at 1:30](https://youtu.be/Qku6eoEOHtY?t=1m29s).

Comment: I don't know the exact title of that one specifically, but it is one of the variations of a particular track. Similar to [My Mother and My Father](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfagIh-meAU) and [Goodbye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u0ILJADEkrs&t=6s)

Comment: Its similar to My mother and My father also thank you, i have searched for this answer for atleast 4 years tlyet coudnt find it and you provided me the ray of hope brother so thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It's an unreleased OST of *Naruto Shippuden* called **Decision** ([YouTube reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96GrLZHdRJU)).